# How to delete a whole folder of branches in git

Tags: git

I have many local branches under different folders eg. bug/the-branch or feat/the-branch.

How can i remove every branch under a certain name?

Comment: try ```git branch list```, then pipe the result to ```grep```, then pipe the result to ```git branch delete```

Comment: If you're willing to play with fire, just do: `rm -rf .git/refs/heads/bug .git/logs/refs/heads/bug`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

List all branches under the name:

```
git for-each-ref --format="%(refname:short)" refs/heads/feat/
```

and delete them one by one:

```
git for-each-ref --format="%(refname:short)" refs/heads/feat/ |
    xargs -n1 git branch -D
```

Please be advised you cannot remove the current branch so first checkout a different branch not under the top name.

Comment: Was about to post the variant `git branch -d $(git for-each-ref --format="%(refname:short)" refs/heads/*/the-branch)`. No need for both answers I guess, yours is fine.

Comment: @RomainValeri `git branch -d` doesn't work with non-merged branch. The rest is ok.

Comment: True, we could just use `-D` instead, my example here was mostly for the subcommands structure, but you're right.

Comment: I was surprised that `git branch --list` accepts a pattern, not but `git branch -D`.

Answer (score 1):

You can delete all branches within the same pattern by doing:

```
git branch -D $(git branch -a | grep <my_pattern> | awk '{print $1}')
```

where `<my_pattern>` is your name.

For example to remove all branches `feat/test`:

```
git branch -D $(git branch -a | grep 'feat/test' | awk '{print $1}')
```

Answer (score 0):

**To delete all branches from a specific folder:**

```
git branch -d $(git for-each-ref --format="%(refname:short)" refs/heads/featureFolderName/)
```

Or to simplify the code, another shorter way.

```
git branch -d $(git for-each-ref refs/heads/featureFolderName/)
```